# Any way to listen again to BBC radio?

Tags: applications, adobe-flash, internet-radio

I would love to listen again to BBC radio in the UK. There was an app called [beebplayer](http://davejohnston.posterous.com/?tag=beebplayer) for watching BBC TV as catch up, and for live radio, but not for radio listen again, although it has now been withdrawn.

So are there any other apps (that don't require flash)? Are there statements from the BBC about Android support anyone could point me to? Is it flash only for ever?

My phone has Android 1.5, so I cannot use the flash player that comes with Android 2.2

**Edit:** Just to be clear, the ["listen again"](http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio4/programmes/a-z/player) service is for catching up with radio programs you've missed, rather than just streaming what is on at the moment. Some are available as [podcasts](http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts), but not all.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any thing preventing you from upgrading to 1.6? I thought all carriers were at that point now. Even the first Google phone can be upgraded to 1.6.

Comment: I think there is a (not official) 2.1 update, but from what I've read the RAM and flash memory in the phone are a bit marginal. I have a T-Mobile Pulse, aka Huawei U8220

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BBC released statements about their support for Android with iPlayer back in June: [BBC iPlayer on mobile: a new version and Adobe Flash 10.1 streaming on all Android 2.2 phones](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/bbcinternet/2010/06/bbc_iplayer_on_mobile_a_new_ve.html) and [BBC iPlayer on Android update](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/bbcinternet/2010/07/bbc_iplayer_on_android_update.html). This all boils down to saying that their current strategy for mobiles is to offer a mobile optimised version of their Flash site, and not to create individual apps for every smartphone out there.

I'm also a Flash-less fan of BBC Radio and TV (though in a better position than you as my manufacturer and carrier have announced that 2.2 is coming very soon), I had Beebplayer on my previous Android phone and it is sorely missed now.

For the moment I just subscribe to the [podcasts of the shows](http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts) I'm interested in (and luckily most of mine are available as podcasts) using the [Google Listen](http://listen.googlelabs.com/) podcast app, this does have the benefit that they work without cutting out while I'm on the tube!

EDIT: Going through the comments on some more recent articles on the BBC Internet blog I've discovered an app called [Myplayer](http://uk.androlib.com/android.application.sns-myplayer-jjiFn.aspx) it seems to offer access to (as far as I can tell) the full iPlayer TV and radio library with both streaming and downloads for later viewing/listening. Picture quality doesn't seem quite as good as I remember from Beebplayer, so presumably its using a different stream. Anyway it's there and seems to work, grab it before "Aunty" spots it!

Newer EDIT: The BBC have released an official iPlayer app, called [BBC iPlayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=bbc.iplayer.android) though this is really just a Flash wrapper around the mobile version of the website and does [require a wifi connection](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/) before it will play most content.

Comment: Note that unfortunately as of V1.100 myPlayer (mid November 2010) has removed all BBC content. See http://www.skynetsoftware.com/myPlayer/historic.aspx and http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=700150

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it, but perhaps [TuneIn Radio](http://www.appbrain.com/app/tunein-radio/tunein.player) will do what you want?  It appears to be internet streams of actual radio stations, I'm sure you can find one that streams BBC.  They have a listing of stations here by location: http://radiotime.com/region/c_0/Browse_Locations.aspx

Comment: The [station listing for national stations in the UK](http://radiotime.com/channel/c_459441/UK_National.aspx) does not include any BBC channel. Also I am looking for catching up with specific programs rather than just streaming. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @Hamish There were some BBC stations in the London region: http://radiotime.com/region/c_100780/London.aspx The only app I could find that does what you want is beeb, and as you know, that was removed

Comment: Ah, interesting, the national stations are listed as London stations. So that provides streaming anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a podcatcher. I use [BeyondPod](http://www.appbrain.com/app/beyondpod-podcast-manager/mobi.beyondpod) which costs $7 but there are many [free](http://www.appbrain.com/app/acast/com.mathias.android.acast) ones in the market (try searching the market for [Podcast](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=podcast) or [Podcatcher](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=podcatcher)). It will allow you to subscribe to a specific BBC show's [podcast feeds](http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts) then download or stream each episode. This works with audio and video (although I don't think BBC supports video podcasts anymore).

I subscribe to several BBC radio podcasts including "The Interview" and "One Planet" and there's one annoying quirk I've noticed:  Unlike many other podcast providers, the BBC only offers the most recent show for download.  You can't download old shows, but once you get set up you can have you podcatcher automatically download each episode and then you can get several weeks behind but have ll the episodes downloaded to your phone.

Comment: I know about the podcasts, and mentioned them in the question. However there are a number of shows I enjoy which aren't available by podcast.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that edit I guess. Beyond that I'm drawing a blank.