# iplayer app for BBC radio programs on 2.3.5?

Tags: applications, internet-radio

Are there any iplayer-like apps to listen to recorded BBC radio programs on 2.3.5?

Comment: Have you seen the answers to this previous question? [Any way to listen again to BBC radio?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1730/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TuneIn Radio](https://market.android.com/details?id=tunein.player&hl=en) has channels for BBC radio, other radio streaming apps probably have them too. TuneIn is a good app, the pro version even lets you record. I am not sure what other features the pro has over the lite version, but I use TuneIn daily.